# Ember Data use different URL for requests

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am beginner for ember.js. I am tried to use ember data for restful api. However there is some convention on the path. For example `App.Post.find()` corresponding to `http://www.example.com/posts`.

However due to my application current pattern, all my list of data is listed under `/post/list`, what shall i do? here i am using post not posts and not using `/posts` but `/post/list`.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple enough to change how the adapter builds the url.  You just extend the current adapter and override the methods that build the url.  In your case I am setting the application adapter (meaning it would apply to all types).  I wasn't positive how the url should have been built when you supply a particular `id`, but I'm pretty sure this is enough to get you started, and you can play the string manipulation game from this point.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter= DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  pathForType: function(type) {
    var camelized = Ember.String.camelize(type);
    return camelized; //Ember.String.pluralize(camelized);
  },
  buildURL: function(type, id) {
    var url = [],
        host = Em.get(this, 'host'),
        prefix = this.urlPrefix();

    if (type) { url.push(this.pathForType(type)); }
    url.push('list');
    if (id) { url.push(id); }

    if (prefix) { url.unshift(prefix); }

    url = url.join('/');
    if (!host && url) { url = '/' + url; }

    return url;
  }  
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/690/edit